# Can fasting destroy our adaptive immune system?

Tags: immune-system, aging, chemotherapy, fasting, stem-cells

Fasting for 72 hours been shown to lead to white blood cell regeneration ([1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4102383/)). The cells basically die after several days, and are created again from stem cells upon feeding. This article describes how it may be useful in chemotherapy and how it related to aging.

I am wondering if cycles of fasting could eventually lead to the destruction of adaptive immune responses developed over time by killing the memory B and T cells.